# Why doesn't Alaoglu's theorem imply that $X^{*}$ is locally compact in the weak* topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I must be missing something basic and simple: If $X$ is a normed vector space and the closed unit ball in $X^{*}$ is weak* compact, and translations and dilations are homeomorphisms, why isn't $X^{*}$ locally compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a locally compact Hausdorff TVS is finite dimensional and thus carries its usual topology. See for example [this blog post by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/).

More concretely for the specific case of $X^*$: The reason that $X^*$ fails to be weak-$*$ locally compact is that the closed unit ball isn't a neighbourhood of $0$ in the weak-$*$ topology.

Comment: Dumb question, just to make sure: any closed ball around the origin is compact in the weak* topology, right?

Comment: Yes. As it is the image of the closed unit ball under the continuous map $x \mapsto cx$.

Comment: I explain the reason in my new answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437750/4280)